# Modifying the look of an NSButton with a CALayer works differently in macOS 10.12 and 10.10

Tags: swift, cocoa, calayer, layer, nsbutton

I am trying to change the look of an NSButton in my app. The button is "Square" and "Momentary Push In".

The code is:

```
let layer = CALayer()
toggleTimespanButton.wantsLayer = true
toggleTimespanButton.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy.onSetNeedsDisplay
layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
layer.cornerRadius = (toggleTimespanButton.bounds.size.width)/2
layer.masksToBounds = true
layer.borderWidth = 1
layer.borderColor = appDelegate.mainColor.cgColor
toggleTimespanButton.layer = layer
```

The button looks fine in macOS 10.12:

[image]

But in macOS 10.10 the button title is not visible. Everything looks and works fine, including the button being white and the border pink etc.

But why is the button title is not visible in macOS 10.10?

I have tried to disable all the lines one by one and the text reappears only when the layer is not added to the button...

Comment: Have you tried setting the `wantsLayer` property of the NSView to `true`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste it when creating the question. I have added it now to the snippet that I posted. But the problem is still there and the button title is invisible...

Comment: Just to clarify: the button title is invisible in macOS 10.10 and looks fine in macOS 10.12.

Comment: This just happened to me with an image-only button in both 10.10 and 10.11. I'll post the solution once I find one.

Comment: I had to implement `draw(_:in:)` of the layer's delegate and explicitly set the `layer.contents` in there to the image to make it appear on each OS version. Not sure if this is of any help in your case but it might be a good starting point.